# SQL: Select * not supported - get column names from subquery

Tags: sql, db2

Showcase is vendor for the platform I use, and it comprises of Showcase server sitting atop our `DB2` DB, intermediary layer to reduce performance impact of `DB2` itself. Showcase Query is their client application and querying interface. It does not support `Select *` and I have hundreds of test relying on *.
Looking to use subquery instead:

```
Select (select COLUMN_NAME from sysibm.columns where TABLE_NAME='sometable')
From 'sometable'
```

This, however returns `"Result of SELECT more than one row"`. I need to reuse this code for tables of varying width, so I don't want to specify columns by their indexes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should never use `SELECT *` in application code. Always explicitly list the columns that your application needs.

Comment: Hi Ansic, welcome, instead of giving us just your query, tell us also what you want to achieve. Building directly from your query might end up solving your problem in the end but won't be the best solution

Comment: Thanks. I have about 20 tables, for each column from these tables I want to run a query to check if they are null and then if not if they are of correct data type

Comment: eDIT your question that you have to iterate over the columns.  that wouldn't be too tricky.

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the column name or * for all (in every DB AFAIK) when selecting.

This will generate the more than one row error for probably all but the simplest of tables.  because there are more than one column in sometable.

```
select COLUMN_NAME from sysibm.columns where TABLE_NAME='sometable'
```

To fix this you have to add more criteria to the where clause

```
    select (
        select COLUMN_NAME from sysibm.columns where TABLE_NAME='sometable' and column_name = 'PARTS'
) 
from sometable.
```